# Access directory as a different user

Tags: linux, files, permissions, nfs, non-root-user

On a Debian (Jessie) server provided by my university, I have a mounted directory (say it's `/MagicDir`) that can *only* be accessed by one user (say `magicuser`). Not even root can access this directory! This is because of some UID/GID mapping that the IT department uses to give me access to this directory without authentication on an NTFS network drive.

Is it possible to allow other users to access this directory through the user `magicuser` somehow? I mean something like a socket/map/gate/soft-link that makes the directory content visible to the other user through `magicuser`?

Please advise! Thanks.

Comment: Trying to circumvent the proper security measures, is asking for trouble. If the university is giving you access and no one else, it must be for a reason. If you feel that, these people who need access to the contents of this NTFS share, ask the university to grant permission to those users. If they are not faculty members, then it is up to you to copy the content to a different place, where it can be accessed by others.

Comment: @MelBurslan It's quite more complicated than this. This drive is there only for storage with no security concerns. It's a 1 TB storage that will be growing over time, and there should not be any limitations on it, but the way the university works is not easily changeable. The reason why it works only for one user is to avoid having username/password in a system that needs it. What I mean is that this whole problem is just a side-effect of what they want to really do. I'm negotiating now with them, but I still would like to see if there's another solution through linux.

Comment: even though I hate the idea, provided where you mount this NTFS share is a machine that you control, i.e., you have root privileges, you can try to export this share as an NFS server share. I am not sure if it will work or not, but it might worth a try. And even when it works, it will be unreliable at best and probably will be a read only access.

Comment: @MelBurslan Could you please provide a reference? And is this the only way? I'm quite surprised it's not as easy as I thought!